# Canvas circle collision, how to work out where circles should move to once collided?

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, physics, game-physics

I am having a go at building a game in html canvas. It's a Air Hockey game and I have got pretty far though it. There are three circles in the game, the disc which is hit and the two controllers(used to hit the disc/circle).

I've got the disc rebounding off the walls and have a function to detect when the disc has collided with a controller. The bit I am struggling with is when the two circle's collide, the controller should stay still and the disc should move away in the correct direction. I've read a bunch of article's but still can't get it right.

Here's a Codepen link my progress so far. You can see that the puck rebounds off the controller but not in the correct direction. You'll also see if the puck comes from behind the controller it goes through it. 
http://codepen.io/allanpope/pen/a01ddb29cbdecef58197c2e829993284?editors=001

I think what I am after is elastic collision but not sure on how to work it out. I've found this article but have been unable to get it working.

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769

Heres is my collision detection function. Self refer's to the disc and the controller[i] is the controller the disc hits.

```
this.discCollision = function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
                // Minus the x pos of one disc from the x pos of the other disc
                var distanceX = self.x - controllers[i].x,
                        // Minus the y pos of one disc from the y pos of the other disc
                        distanceY = self.y - controllers[i].y,
                        // Multiply each of the distances by itself
                        // Squareroot that number, which gives you the distance between the two disc's
                        distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY),
                        // Added the two disc radius together
                        addedRadius = self.radius + controllers[i].radius;


                // Check to see if the distance between the two circles is smaller than the added radius
                // If it is then we know the circles are overlapping
                if (distance <= addedRadius) {

                    var newVelocityX = (self.velocityX * (self.mass - controllers[i].mass) + (2 * controllers[i].mass * controllers[i].velocityX)) / (self.mass + controllers[i].mass);
                    var newVelocityY = (self.velocityY * (self.mass - controllers[i].mass) + (2 * controllers[i].mass * controllers[i].velocityX)) / (self.mass + controllers[i].mass);

                    self.velocityX = newVelocityX;
                    self.velocityY = newVelocityY;

                    self.x = self.x + newVelocityX;
                    self.y = self.y + newVelocityY; 

                } 
            }   

    }
```

**Updated**

Deconstructed a circle collision demo & tried to implement their collision formula. This is it below, works for hitting the puck/disc forward & down but wont hit the back backwards or up for some reason.

```
this.discCollision = function() {

            for (var i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
                    // Minus the x pos of one disc from the x pos of the other disc
                    var distanceX = self.x - controllers[i].x,
                            // Minus the y pos of one disc from the y pos of the other disc
                            distanceY = self.y - controllers[i].y,
                            // Multiply each of the distances by itself
                            // Squareroot that number, which gives you the distance between the two disc's
                            distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY),
                            // Added the two disc radius together
                            addedRadius = self.radius + controllers[i].radius;

                    // Check to see if the distance between the two circles is smaller than the added radius
                    // If it is then we know the circles are overlapping                                
                    if (distance < addedRadius) {

                            var normalX = distanceX / distance,
                                normalY = distanceY / distance,
                                midpointX = (controllers[i].x + self.x) / 2,
                                midpointY = (controllers[i].y + self.y) / 2,
                                delta = ((controllers[i].velocityX - self.velocityX) * normalX) + ((controllers[i].velocityY - self.velocityY) * normalY),
                                deltaX = delta*normalX,
                                deltaY = delta*normalY;

                            // Rebound puck
                            self.x = midpointX + normalX * self.radius;
                            self.y = midpointY + normalY * self.radius;
                            self.velocityX += deltaX;
                            self.velocityY += deltaY;

                            // Accelerate once hit
                            self.accelerationX = 3;
                            self.accelerationY = 3;

                    }
            }

    }
```

Comment: new direction will be the sum of two vectors. v1 = vx,vy of ball. v2 =  perpendicular to edge of 2nd ball with magnitude equal to v1.

Comment: since controller is stationary you can assume its mass his huge, or you can use different formula that assumes no momentum is absorbed or transferred only redirected.

Comment: try out this site to visualize it https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/vector-addition/vector-addition_en.html

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, still not 100% following on how to figure out the formula. What you mentioned 'or you can use different formula that assumes no momentum is absorbed or transferred only redirected.' might be a better option, do you have any ideas of what that formula might look like?

Comment: Suppose ball was a wall, and the angle Q at ball is approaching the wall. Then angle at which itd be leaving would be 180-Q for left wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with my code was the user controller was attached to the mouse. When a collision would happen, the function would run constantly because the circles where still touching due to the mouse position. I changed my code so the controller is controlled by the users keyboard.

I also asked for help on reddit & got some help with my collision code. Some good resources where linked.
(http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3cjivi/having_a_go_at_building_an_air_hockey_game_stuck/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at these types of math problems, but it looks like you need to rotate your vectors around sine and cosine angles. I will point you at a working example and the source code that drives it. I did not derive this example.

I solved just the circle collision detection part of this problem recently, but one solution I came across includes code for establishing new vector directions. Ira Greenburg hosts his original source at [processing.org](https://processing.org/examples/circlecollision.html). Ira further cites Keith Peter's Solution in Foundation Actionscript Animation: Making Things Move!

I copied Ira's code into Processing's Javascript mode then pushed it to [Github Pages](http://jameswclark.github.io/CFC2015/Processing2D/IrasCircleCollision/web-export/index.html) so you can see it before you try it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not great at these Math problems either, first time I've tried doing something like this. I checked out your solution but I'd rather stay away from using an external library.